trying to send data to an outside website from Elementor forms. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the website:  I want to populate the ACBL number from my form. https://cloud.bridgefinesse.com/C163246Profile.html. The form field ID in Elementor is "acblno".  I'm using redirect after submission with the following.  https://cloud.bridgefinesse.com/C163246Profile.html?acblno=[field id="acblno"]
It went to the page but did not populate the field.
